# How do I deploy a Google Cloud Function (2nd generation)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I've previously only used Cloud Functions of gen. 1 but now plan to move to 2nd generation and is just trying to deploy/test a first basic function. I'm just taking the Google sample for a [storage triggered function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#functions_tutorial_helloworld_storage-nodejs) and try to deploy it, but it keeps failing.
This is what it looks like:

```
> gcloud functions deploy nodejs-finalize-function --gen2 --runtime=nodejs16 --project myproject --region=europe-west3 --source=. --entry-point=handleImage --trigger-event-filters='type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized' --trigger-event-filters='bucket=se_my_images'

Preparing function...done.                                                                                                                                                            
X Deploying function...                                                                                                                                                               
  ✓ [Build] Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west3/a8355043-adf0-4485-a510-1d54b7e11111?project=123445666123]                 
  ✓ [Service]                                                                                                                                                                         
  ✓ [Trigger]                                                                                                                                                                         
  - [ArtifactRegistry] Deleting function artifacts in Artifact Registry...                                                                                                            
  . [Healthcheck]                                                                                                                                                                     
  . [Triggercheck]                                                                                                                                                                    
Failed.                                                                                                                                                                               
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=7, message=Creating trigger failed for projects/myproject/locations/europe-west3/triggers/nodejs-finalize-function-898863: The Cloud Storage service account for your bucket is unable to publish to Cloud Pub/Sub topics in the specified project.
To use GCS CloudEvent triggers, the GCS service account requires the Pub/Sub Publisher (roles/pubsub.publisher) IAM role in the specified project. (See https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/quickstart-storage#before-you-begin)
```

The error looks easy to understand, but I have aded the Pub/Sub Publisher role to all my service accounts now (the ones listed below) and I still keep getting the same error.

```
>gcloud iam service-accounts list --project myproject
DISPLAY NAME                        EMAIL                                                   DISABLED
firebase-adminsdk                   firebase-adminsdk-u2x33@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com  False
Default compute service account     930445666575-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com      False
backend-dev                         backend-dev@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com              False
App Engine default service account  myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com                      False
```

I don't know how to move forward from here so I hope someone can help.

*** **EDIT** ***.
I added the role to the listed service accounts in the GCP console, IAM > Permissions > View By Principal page/view where I used the Edit Principal button to assign an additional role (Pub/Sub Publisher) to the service accounts (note that I added the role to all my listed service accounts since I'm not 100% sure which one is used by GCP for cloud deployment).

[image: IAM Role assignment]

Comment: The error message is clear, the service account does not have the Pub/Sub Publisher role. So the question becomes how you added that role to the Cloud Storage service account for your bucket.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question with details on how I assigned the role.

Comment: 1) Add the output from the command `gcloud eventarc triggers describe TRIGGER` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/eventarc/triggers/describe. 2) Is the bucket `se_my_images` in the same project?

Comment: Yes, the bucket is in the same project. Running the suggested command (after adding the --location parameter) gives:  

`gcloud eventarc triggers describe TRIGGER --location europe-west3
ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.describe) NOT_FOUND: Resource 'projects/myproject/locations/europe-west3/triggers/TRIGGER' was not found
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
  resourceName: projects/myproject/locations/europe-west3/triggers/TRIGGER`

Comment: The word **TRIGGER** is a placeholder. Review command documentation in my link. Put the results in your question.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used eventarc so missed that... Anyway I am not sure which trigger to try to describe but if I list all triggers with `gcloud eventarc triggers list` I get `Listed 0 items` back. Which seems correct since the deployment failed on the trigger creation step.

Comment: The document that you linked in your question uses Eventarc. The error message is regarding Cloud Storage events (publish). My suggestion is to go back over the document and double-check each of your steps. Note: the list might be empty because the deployment failed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I've tried the tutorial a couple of times already with the same result and it is very basic so I can't really see what to change. Also, the error message says _the GCS service account requires the Pub/Sub Publisher IAM Role_ which I to the best of my understanding already have so seems to be something shaky with the implementation. Let's see if someone else has any idea where to continue investigating.

Comment: I am convinced at this point that you are adding the Publisher role to the wrong service account. Please review the Cloud Storage Service Agent: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects#service-agents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you are already using gcloud cli, i suggest you follow the step 2 which says:

```
PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)

PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects list --filter="project_id:$PROJECT_ID" --format='value(project_number)')

SERVICE_ACCOUNT=$(gsutil kms serviceaccount -p $PROJECT_NUMBER)

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
  --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --role roles/pubsub.publisher
```

After these 4 cmd's, you should have no problems.. I don't use gcp interface for iam purposes, since all my iam policies are uploaded by terraform/terragrunt.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later today but you might be on to something. When I just check `SERVICE_ACCOUNT=$(gsutil kms serviceaccount -p $PROJECT_NUMBER)` I get an account like `service-930445666xxx@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com` which I cannot see when I do `gcloud iam service-accounts list`.  

Why it's not visible when listing acounts I can't understand but hopefully I can just add the role to this "hidden" account and it will work...

Comment: Yes, after doing the add-iam-policy you should have that SA listed by `gcloud iam service-accounts list` or presented in gcp interface. Best, David.