# Why doesn't my Cloud Function (2nd gen) trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

After getting [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74285987/how-do-i-deploy-a-google-cloud-function-2nd-generation) deploying the sample code for a [cloud function with a storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#object_finalize) I now get the function deployed just fine, but now it won't trigger :-(

The function is deployed:
[image: deployment]

The deployed code (per the tutorial):

```
'use strict';

// [START functions_cloudevent_storage]
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

// Register a CloudEvent callback with the Functions Framework that will
// be triggered by Cloud Storage.
functions.cloudEvent('imageAdded', cloudEvent => {
  console.log(`Event ID: ${cloudEvent.id}`);
  console.log(`Event Type: ${cloudEvent.type}`);

  const file = cloudEvent.data;
  console.log(`Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
  console.log(`File: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
  console.log(`Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
  console.log(`Updated: ${file.updated}`);
});
// [END functions_cloudevent_storage]
```

The deploy command I used:

```
gcloud functions deploy xxx-image-handler --gen2 --runtime=nodejs16 --project myproject --region=europe-west3 --source=. --entry-point=imageAdded --trigger-event-filters='type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized' --trigger-event-filters='bucket=xxx_report_images'
```

To test I just uploaded a text file from command line:

```
gsutil cp test-finalize.txt gs://xxx_report_images/test-finalize.txt
```

Which worked fine, and the file was uploaded to the xxx_report_images bucket (which also is in the europe-west3 region) but the function is never triggered, which I can see by 0 items in the log:

```
gcloud beta functions logs read xxx-image-handler --gen2 --limit=100 --region europe-west3
Listed 0 items.
```

What is going on here? This seems very straight-forward and I fail to see what I'm missing, so hopefully I can get some guidance.

**** **EDIT 1** *****

Regarding comment 1 below. I can see (in the Eventarch trigger list, picture below) that the service account used by eventarch is xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

[image: trigger table]

And I can see in the IAM Principals list that this indeed is the Default compute service account, which has the Editor role. I also explicitly added the Eventarc Connection Publisher role to this service account but without success (I assume the Editor role already contains this role, but just to be sure...). So I guess the issue is not related to your suggestion (?).

BTW. I tried the suggested `gcloud compute project-info describe --format="value(defaultServiceAccount)"` but just got `Could not fetch resource: - Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/myproject'` and I couldn't figure out which role to add to which serviceaccount to enable this. However, as seen above I found the info in the Eventarc section in GCP instead.

**** **EDIT 2** ****.

Indeed after more testing I think I have nailed it down to being a permission issue on Eventarc, just like suggested in the comment. I've posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74313620/how-to-give-google-cloud-eventarc-correct-permission-so-it-can-trigger-a-cloud-f) which is more specific.

Comment: Could it be that the service account that is used for your eventarc trigger is not allowed to trigger your function? By default this is the default compute engine service account so the account you get when you run this: `gcloud compute project-info describe --format="value(defaultServiceAccount)"`. This account usually has Editor roles on the project but there are org policies that disable that.

Comment: I don't think so, please see Edit 1 above.

Comment: My workflows, for some reason weren't triggering. I had set up a bucket, which was configured with an eventArc trigger which would send finalized objects to a workflow, what @TimoDempwolf suggested was in fact exactly what was going wrong, cheers!

Giving the serviceAccount permissions to publish messages (roles/pubsub.publisher)  did fix the issue for me.