# How to give Google Cloud Eventarc correct permission so it can trigger a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I have succesfully deployed a 2nd generation cloud function with a storage trigger per the [google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#object_finalize).

The Cloud Function works when I run a test command in the shell. But if I try for real by uploading a file to my bucket the could function is not invoked.

I can see that the event triggers the pubsub topic:

[image]

And in Eventarc I can see signs of the problem:

[image]

So, my layman analyse of why the cloud function invokation fails is that I lack some permission for Eventarc to receive the message from PubSub (?). I have read [Eventarc troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/troubleshooting) and [Eventarc accesscontrol](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/access-control) and tried to add the eventarc admin role to the eventarc serviceaccount (as seen in image below) but to no result. (I've also added it to any other service account I can find, made the compute service account project owner, etc. but no luck). What am I missing?

[image]

(Note, I had an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294882/why-doesnt-my-cloud-function-2nd-gen-trigger) about this but with broader scope but I opted for a new, more specific question)

Comment: Have you given the needed permissions to the identity that triggers `Eventarc` and the `Cloud function` ?

Comment: The xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaacount.com has the 'Editor' role. I have tried with also giving it 'Owner' role and 'Eventarc Admin' role without any success. Maybe there is yet some other role that must be added but I fail to see which one. EDIT: Thanks, just saw your posted answer. Will try!

Comment: any progress to this issue?

Comment: Maybe giving ```roles/storage.admin``` to the ```<PROJECTNUM>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com``` and then making the cloud function accessible without authentication would work. For me it did. I also made the cloud function for internal traffic only so accessing w/o authentication is not that big of risk.

Comment: Any news on this? We cannot deploy a function with the V2 ```Permission denied while using the Eventarc Service Agent. ```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Pub/Sub service account has the `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role. This could be the case if you enabled the Pub/Sub service account on or before April 8, 2021. (https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/roles-permissions)

If you create a new eventarc trigger in the console you'll get a warning when the Pub/Sub service account doesn't have this role and you can enable it right there.

Comment: This was the problem for me that i was seeing the permission denied errors. So after granting grant the Service Account Token Creator role (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) on the project to the Pub/Sub service agent it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Stumble across the same issue, and found the solution at the "Permissions" tab of the cloud function I was trying to trigger.

[image: Warning message on cloud function about necessary roles]

Here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Find the service account that eventarc is using;
2. On IAM page give that principal the "Cloud Run Invoker" role;

Seems to be only necessary with the 2nd generation cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

You used the `Compute Engine` default Service Account.

You need to give the needed permissions to this Service Account :

According to the documentation :

> Make sure the runtime service account key you are using for your
> Application Default Credentials has either the
> cloudfunctions.serviceAgent role or the storage.buckets.{get, update}
> and the resourcemanager.projects.get permissions. For more information
> on setting these permissions, see Granting, changing, and revoking
> access to resources.

Please check in `IAM` page if the default Service Account has the following permissions :

- cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
- storage.buckets.{get, update}
- resourcemanager.projects.get

Also, don't hesitate to check in `Cloud logging` to see the exact error and the missing permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding those permissions didn't change anything. And, as far as I can see, Eventarc doesn't write anything to Cloud Logging. The only indication I get on the failure is in the Eventarc Trigger Details where the Invocations chart indicates `permission_denied`.

Answer (score 0):

After working through the permissions issues I also had to allow the pubsub service account like so...

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "pubsubtoken" {
  project = "example"
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member  = "serviceAccount:service-####@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Where ### is the gcp project number  , so the trigger now works, when copying files to the bucket.

I plan to populate this from data shortly, like data.google_project.project.number

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar case. I was trying to activate a Workflow with Eventarc whenever a new file was created in a Bucket.

I observed the same behavior on my Eventarc screen.

The solution was to assign the role **roles/workflows.invoker** to the Service Account (SA) used in the Eventarc (I used the same SA for both Eventarc and the Workflow).

You may need to assign the role **roles/cloudfunctions.invoker** to your SA.

If you notice, the graph you post in your question is the *Invocations* graph, so my proposal makes sense.